# Algolia Undeclared Property Filter

Tags: algolia

I'd like to filter Algolia by missing properties, is this possible?

At the moment we are using:

`filters:(expires=0 OR expires<1506338742)`

Which works fine for content that has the `expires` property, but not all content does, so they get omitted from the results.

Is there a way of adding an extra condition where property `expires` is not set/undefined? I have tried a few different variations but can't get it to work, and the documentation doesn't seem to cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia offers no way to filter on the presence of an attribute.
As a result, the solution to your issue depends on the expected results.

Here is one way you could return results that have not expiration attribute.

At indexing time, push another attribute `has_expiration` along with every record.
This attribute should be boolean that will equal `true` if expiration should be taken into account or `false` otherwise.

Then you need to adapt your `filters` query parameter as follow: `filters:(expires=0 OR expires<1506338742) OR has_expiration=0`

Comment: Thanks Ray, appreciate your response. This is effectively what I am doing by setting expires to 0 but we have some old data in the index :)

Comment: Any chance you could re-push that data?
Otherwise you could `browse` your existing entries and re-push them. See https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/pagination/#browse

Comment: Yeah, I had to, but some of the data wasn't updating which was odd. I completely reindexed which resolved but it got me to thinking would it be possible to just match those without the property :)